# Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [stored-proc-outbound-gateway]

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring-Integration in my project. I am trying to import a configuration file within another configuration file. The main configuration file code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd ">

    <import resource="spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>

    <!-- map of namespace prefix to URI -->
    <util:map id="xmlMessageNamespace">
        <entry key="SOAP" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
    </util:map>
    <int:channel id="jobDesignerInputChannel" />
    <int:channel id="cs-exceptionHandlingChannel" />

    <bean id="msgHandler" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.PQMessageHandler" />
    <bean id="xmlAggregator" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.XmlAggregator" />
    <bean id="httpOutboundGatewayHandler" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.HttpOutboundGatewayHandler" />
    <bean id="xmlFilter" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.XmlFilter" />

    <int:chain input-channel="jobDesignerInputChannel" >

        <int-xml:xpath-header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
            <int-xml:header name="${headerNames.legacySystem}"  xpath-expression="//LegacySystem"  evaluation-type="STRING_RESULT"  overwrite="true" />   
        </int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>        

        <!-- Some of the AWD jobs contain Business Area info under <code> tag, we should not keep that business area info in the 
        header since it is not required.This will help us in identifying AWD and Non-AWD jobs-->
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="${headerNames.businessArea}" expression="#xpath(payload, '//businessArea/Code', 'boolean') ? null : #xpath(payload, '//businessArea')"/>
        </int:header-enricher>

        <int:router expression="${routing.jobChannel}"/>
    </int:chain>



    <int:chain input-channel="cs-exceptionHandlingChannel">
        <!-- Service Activator to handle the errors --> 
        <int:service-activator  ref="msgHandler" method="handleError" />

        <!-- Router to routing the error messages to appropriate job channel for xsl transormation -->      
        <int:router expression="${routing.jobErrorChannel}"/>
    </int:chain>           
</beans>
```

But, the following error is thrown when the above file is trying to import:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [JobDesigner-springintegration.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [CustomerServiceRD/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [CustomerServiceRD/JobDesigner-springintegration.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [stored-proc-outbound-gateway]
Offending resource: file [D:\CustomerServiceRD-Workspace\CustomerServiceRD\csWeb\container\conf\CustomerServiceRD\spring-integration\Jobs\PQProviderSearch.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:271)
```

The file that needs to be imported is here(PQProviderSearch.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd  ">

    <int:channel id="PQProviderSearch-InputChannel" />

    <int:chain input-channel="PQProviderSearch-InputChannel" output-channel="PQProviderSearch-LegacySystem-Router">

        <!-- Split the Search Request Params from Xml  -->
        <int-xml:xpath-splitter>
            <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//ProviderSearch"  namespace-map="xmlMessageNamespace" />
        </int-xml:xpath-splitter>

        <!-- Store the original payload in header for future purpose -->
        <int:header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
            <int:header name="${headerNames.originalPayload}" expression="payload" />   
        </int:header-enricher>  

        <!-- Store the job name in header for future purpose -->
        <int:header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
           <int:header name="jobName" value="PQProviderSearch"  />
        </int:header-enricher> 

    </int:chain>                

    <!-- Router routes the message to the appropriate legacy system channel -->
    <int:header-value-router input-channel="PQProviderSearch-LegacySystem-Router"
                             header-name="${headerNames.legacySystem}" >
            <int:mapping value="${legacySystem.amisys}"       channel="PQProviderSearch-Amisys-Channel"/>
            <int:mapping value="${legacySystem.powerstepp}"   channel="PQProviderSearch-PowerStepp-Channel"/>
            <int:mapping value="${legacySystem.mhc}"          channel="PQProviderSearch-MHC-Channel"/>      
            <int:mapping value="${legacySystem.awd}"          channel="PQProviderSearch-AWD-Channel"/>      
    </int:header-value-router>

    <!-- PowerStepp Channel -->
    <int:channel id="PQProviderSearch-PowerStepp-Channel" />
    <int:chain input-channel="PQProviderSearch-PowerStepp-Channel"  output-channel="PQProviderSearch-ExternalSystem-Response" >

        <int:service-activator ref="msgHandler" method="buildStoredProcOutboundGatewayRequest" />

        <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
                        id="PQProviderSearch-PowerSTEPP-StoredProcedure" 
                        auto-startup="true"
                        data-source="routingDataSource" 
                        stored-procedure-name="${PQProviderSearch.storedProcedureName}"
                        skip-undeclared-results="true"
                        ignore-column-meta-data="true"  
                        use-payload-as-parameter-source = "false" 
                        expect-single-result="true" >

                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="ROWREQ" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="DBGFLG" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="SECDAT" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="PROVNO" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="PRVLST" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="PRVFST" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="FEDNUM" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="SPECCD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="NPINUM" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="ZIPCOD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="ROWREQ" value="${PQProviderSearch.ROWREQ}" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="DBGFLG" value="${PQProviderSearch.DBGFLG}" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="SECDAT" value="${PQProviderSearch.SECDAT}" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="PROVNO" expression="payload.PrvNum" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="PRVLST" expression="payload.PrvLName" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="PRVFST" expression="payload.PrvFName" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="FEDNUM" expression="payload.PrvTaxID" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="SPECCD" expression="payload.PrvSpec" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="NPINUM" expression="payload.PrvNPI" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="ZIPCOD" expression="payload.PrvZip" />

                <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="rowMapper" row-mapper="com.dsths.cs.awd.utils.ResultSetRowMapper"/>

        </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

    </int:chain>    




    <!-- Service Activator to build the Message from the ExternalSystem Result -->
    <int:channel id="PQProviderSearch-ExternalSystem-Response" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQProviderSearch-ExternalSystem-Response"
                           output-channel="PQProviderSearch-XsltTransformInputChannel" 
                           ref="msgHandler" 
                           method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" />


    <int:chain  input-channel="PQProviderSearch-XsltTransformInputChannel"  output-channel="PQProviderSearch-XsltTransformOutputChannel" >

        <!-- Transformer to transform the resultXml to the user understandable form using XSLT -->
        <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQProviderSearch}"  /> 

        <!-- Transformer to transform the resultXml with count to the user understandable form using XSLT -->
        <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQProviderSearchCount}"  />

    </int:chain>

        <!-- check whether the call is from PQProviderSearch job or PQIssueDetails job and redirect the response accordingly -->
    <int:router input-channel="PQProviderSearch-XsltTransformOutputChannel"  expression="headers['jobName'] ?: 'routingChannelForProviderSearch'"

                resolution-required="false"  >  

       <int:mapping value="PQProviderSearch" channel="PQProviderSearch-FinalEnrich"/>
       <int:mapping value="PQIssueDetails" channel="PQIssueDetails-PQProviderSearch-Response"/>
    </int:router>


    <!--  Service Activator to build the jobResponse xml making use of jobRequestXml and xlst transformed xml-->
    <int:channel id="PQProviderSearch-FinalEnrich" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQProviderSearch-FinalEnrich" 
                           ref="msgHandler" 
                           method="enrichPayloadXml" />


    <int:recipient-list-router id="custmRouter" input-channel="routingChannelForProviderSearch"
                timeout="1234"
                ignore-send-failures="true"
                apply-sequence="true">
    <int:recipient channel="PQProviderSearch-FinalEnrichLast"/>
    <int:recipient channel="PQIssueDetails-PQProviderSearch-Response"/>
    </int:recipient-list-router>    

    <!--  Service Activator to build the jobResponse xml making use of jobRequestXml and xlst transformed xml-->
    <int:channel id="PQProviderSearch-FinalEnrichLast" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQProviderSearch-FinalEnrichLast" 
                           ref="msgHandler" 
                           method="enrichPayloadXml" />                            

</beans>
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [stored-proc-outbound-gateway]

You have to check the classpath of your application, when you run it.

Even if your IDE allows to use those custom tags, it doesn't matter that at runtime you have correct environment.

Maybe an issue is around a wrong (old?) version of Spring Integration: stored procedure adapters have been introduced since 2.1.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for quick response.